# Mongo database root user can't edit users

Tags: mongodb, mongohub

I've an annoying problem with my mongo db (v2.6). I've added a root user to it, with role:

```
{role: "root", db: "admin"}
```

My problem is, that I wanted to set authentication for other databases, but I can add user, without command line. I've used this in command line:

```
db.createUser({user: "dbuser", pwd: "dbpass", roles: ["dbAdmin"]})
```

It's ok. But I'm not a true command-line-lover, so I like AdminUIs. I'm using MongoHUB for it. I can login, add/remove collections on any database, but I can't create user for databases. I get this error:

```
not authorized on admin to execute command
```

I've read this on the manual:

```
"root does not include the ability to insert data directly into the system.users and system.roles collections in the admin database."
```

So what is the correct role for me?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can get what you want by adding the restore role...though it's upsetting to me that MongoHUB is manging users in this way. It should be using commands like createUser for maximum security.

Comment: Many thanks! You saved me! :) Write an answer based on this post, and I'll give you the points :)